# How Can I Create a Temporary Password

Tags: postgresql

When I create a new user, I give them a "temporary" password and tell them to change it as soon as they log in. How can I effectively enforce this?

I tried using `ALTER USER VALID UNTIL 'near-future-timestamp';` but as it turns out this expiration date does not get reset when the user changes their password.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can by using PostgreSQL internal authentication.

Check https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4836F43E.4050607@otg-nc.com:

> I think the best you could do would be to tie authentication into some 
>   external system that requires a password change after a specified 
>   interval.  This can be accomplished with LDAP, Kerberos, or PAM.
>   However, I don't think that the native mechanism will allow you to do 
>   what you are trying to accomplish.

This is rather old, but, AFAIK it's still valid.

Answer (score 0):

According to Postgresql [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createuser.html) there is no option to set temporary password
or allow to change the password when the first login.